# Parsing application.yml in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, spring-boot

I have a application.yml file in my application

```
spring:  
  profiles:  
    active: default,dev  
app:  
  properties:  
    lucene:  
      indexInfoFile: ${spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.search.default.indexBase}/index.properties  
      reindex: false  
    storage:  
      home: ${user.home}/xxx  
      basePath: ${app.properties.storage.home}/uploads/  
      staticFilesPrefix: /files/  
      appUrl: /app/
```

---

```
spring:  
   profiles: dev    

   http:    
       multipart:  
         max-file-size: 3MB  
         max-request-Size: 3MB
```

Now in my controller, I am trying to get the data from yml file  and the code for the same is

```
$http.get('/resources/application.yml').then(function (response) {  
        console.log('entire data is ', response.data);                    

         console.log('basePath is ', response.data.basePath);  

      });
```

Entire Data is printing perfectly ( the whole yml file is getting printed) but when ever I am trying to print a particular property like basePath, max-file-size etc  I am getting "undefined error".

My question is how to get a particular property to be printed on the console.

Answer (score 2):

I would not recommend to access the yml file directly in Angular.
The format is difficult to parse (hence your question) and you sooner or later you may not want to expose all your confguration details.

Instead create a rest controller in spring mapped to something like /config
Let spring inject all the configuration values you need using @Value and return a Map or a simple PoJo with exactly the attributes you need.

Spring will convert this to JSON which you can easily be consumed in Angular.

Comment: We followed the same Stefan. Thanks for the response

Comment: It is a solution, yes but if the URL request defined in AngularJs depends on values in yml ? what is the best solution ?
Like environment that should be put differently in the URL